# Error when mounting an open directory using rclone mount

Tags: windows, windows-10, mount, directory-listing

I'm trying to mount an open directory (example: http://sv2.mybia2music.com/s2/Music/1391/) on windows 10 using `rclone mount`. I'm using rclone-v1.42-windows-amd64

It just throws errors and I can't access the drive but it shows up in Windows explorer. Trying to access it says `K:\ is not accessible. The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.`

**Input:**

```
rclone mount test:http://sv2.mybia2music.com/s2/Music/1391/ K:
```

**Output:**

```
The service rclone has been started.

2018/07/23 20:31:21 ERROR : /: Dir.Stat error: error listing "": directory not found
2018/07/23 20:31:21 ERROR : IO error: error listing "":directory not found
2018/07/23 20:31:21 ERROR : /: Dir.Stat error: error listing "": directory not found
2018/07/23 20:31:21 ERROR : IO error: error listing "":directory not found
2018/07/23 20:31:21 ERROR : /: Dir.Stat error: error listing "": directory not found
2018/07/23 20:31:21 ERROR : IO error: error listing "":directory not found
```

Comment: I wonder if that `http://sv2.mybia2music.com/s2/Music/1391` resource needs a credential specified with the `--rc-user` switch and so forth. Also test with `--debug-fuse` and see if that gives any further clue. I tried connecting to a slow WebDAV share with this tool and it times out using it but that resource is on a very slow Internet connection if I recall correctly. I'm curious what you determine with this though.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Forgive my ignorance and thank you for the answer but why would I need `--rc-user` for an open directory? [Here's the debug](https://pastebin.com/cFJgr8Qu) from using `--debug-fuse`. I'm new to rclone so I have no idea what it means

Comment: I'm new to rclone as well but tested with it per a client remote WebDAV need over slow links though. I wasn't sure if the web browser passed in a different or implicit security context whereas rclone did not. The lines showing `FILE_OPEN, CreateOptions=200000, FileAttributes=0, Security=NULL, AllocationSize=0:0, AccessToken=00000000000002EC[PID=2864], DesiredAccess=80, GrantedAccess=0, ShareAccess=7` look interesting for security NULL, desired, and granted access being different for example. This seems to be for a FILE_OPEN operatation too perhaps.

Comment: I don't know what that means exactly but seems like what it requested access wise with a PID and/or Access Token and what it was granted with NULL security was not granted or something like that. Again, I don't know what this means exactly or if that's the case but if you have an HTTP resource with a credential you can use the `--rc-user` and I think `--rc-pass` or whatever and see if it does grant and compare the debug log differences with that does and does not work to help troubleshoot. I guess that was my thought process perhaps.